# Google DataFlow pipeline stuck draining with large negative data freshness for beam.io.WriteToBigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a DataFlow pipeline that occasionally (I've seen it twice now) gets stuck draining. It has been draining for 4 days now. Execution Details show a large negative output data freshness for a `beam.io.WriteToBigQuery` sink:

[image]

I'm not certain that the negative data freshness is causing the hang, but it feels like a good place to start. Looking for suggestions for how to diagnose. I have not found anything by Googling.

Comment: This could be due to one of the steps not completing the existing  bundle. Dataflow cannot cannot drain till existing bundles are properly finalized (for example, BigQuery data is flushed). Do you see any errors in Cloud Console worker logs ?

Comment: No, no errors in the log. I get an occasional warning about "crash-sender.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'" but that seems to be innocuous.